# Debugging WebRx applications

Tags: javascript, webrx

my problem is best described in code. Here are two fragments.

Html part:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: bookmarks">
  <li>
    <a data-bind="text: $data, attr: {href: $data}"></a>
    <button data-bind="command:{command: delete, parameter: $index}">-</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript part:

```
function Demo() {
  this.bookmarks = wx.list(['http://google.com', 'http://facebook.com'])
  this.delete = wx.command(function(idx) {
    this.bookmarks.removeAt(idx)
  }, this)
}

wx.applyBindings(new Demo())
```

As you can imagine, it doesn't work. But I don't get any error. Is there a way to get an error when a binding is incorrect. Like in this case I should have used `command:{command: $parent.@delete, parameter: $index}`.

Any other tips on debugging would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your observation is correct. The library does not throw an error nor does it emit anything to the browser's console. This is by design. A binding error should not bring down the entire application. Unfortunately this is not very convenient for the developer. Therefore WebRx will soon sport a "Developer Mode" (https://github.com/WebRxJS/WebRx/issues/19)

Comment: This is good news. Thanks!